# Keeping iterator in consistent state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I was reading this post to understand how things are done in Sql Server:
http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/

If I understand it correctly, data is being sent to client as is being needed. Before we fetch next batch of data to the client, execution of query is suspended. If we do range scan then metadata about last returned row will be stored somewhere. 
What happens if in the meantime there is a page split and last returned row is on the new page?
Is this possible? Does this operator/iterator (clustered index scan for example) holds latch on page whole time?
This would be extremely inefficient, so Sql Server must have some other way to keep it in sync?

My question is - what metadata is stored and how does Sql Server keep it in sync?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No SQL Server does not hold a latch. The storage engine keeps track of the current index scan position using a "cookie". The cookie is revalidated if another process takes a latch (of a type that means the page might have been changed) on the same page since the cookie was acquired.

If the cookie (scan position) is no longer valid, the b-tree structure is traversed (using key + uniquifier information stored in the cookie) to reacquire the correct position, and the cookie updated.

In case it is of interest, here is a stack capture when the saved position is validated:

[image: Stack trace]

And another one just after cookie validation has failed due to a concurrent incompatible latch. The engine is repositioning the scan position using a seek to find the correct new position:

[image: Stack trace]

There are [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177426.aspx) related to cookie activity, for example `Scan Point Revalidations/sec` and `Used page/leaf page cookie`.

There is no public documentation that describes exactly how this all works. The details above are based on observations, subsequently confirmed in conversations with Paul Randal and Bob Ward.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, the database metadata and the user data that you insert/select/update/delete are in general protected by Transactions, Isolation Levels, Latches, and Locks.

Since your question is about metadata, a simple example:

- Locks queue up as necessary, so that they can be processed in 'order' according what ever constraints exist at the moment. Of course, many queries can run simultaneously.
- If there is a Schema Stability lock (or a whole stream of Schema Stability locks), this keeps the metadata of those locked objects from changing until the locks are released.
- If there is a Schema Modification lock, once it reaches the head of the queue, it will  block all of the following Schema Stability locks, execute the modification, then free up the lock when finished.

If that is insufficient for your question: "What metadata is stored and how does Sql Server keep it in sync?" then I suggest reading books such as:

**Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals (Developer Reference)** authored by Kalen Delaney, Paul Randal, Kimberly Tripp, Conor Cunningham, Adam Machanic, and Benjamin Nevarez. (All SQL Server powerhouses.) A link, in case you need one:

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-Internals-Developer-Reference/dp/0735626243/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735626243)